# Rails 4 Ecommerce App using collection_select/select: how to correctly implement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, collection-select

I have a Product model with the following columns:

```
name:string
price:integer
```

I also have a cart model, line_item model, an orders controller: pretty basic but you get the idea.

What I need to do (and have done) is add size (since it's for tshirts) and color to the Product model. Fair enough,

```
rails g migration AddSizeToProducts size:string
```

works just fine and similarly for color.

The way the buying process is set up is as follows:

1. *select shirt (one page)*
2. *after selecting shirt, takes you to next page*
3. *on this page, you will select both the color and size for the shirt.*

From what I've gathered, using `select` will not be tied to the database, so I suppose `collection_select` would be more appropriate here? Or would something like this be OK?

```
<%= select @product, :id, [ ["Small",1], ["Medium",2], ["Large",3]] %>
```

Also, how would I "prepopulate" these fields with sizes ie small/med/large and colors ie black/blue/white without having them associated to a particular product before a product is selected (from step 1 above)?

Any input on the matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> without having them associated to a particular product

This confused me - surely you'd want to associate the select box with a particular product's options?

---

I would personally make sure the "buy process" is set up to pass the product ID throughout. I'd do this by using a [nested resource in the routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products do
    get :step2 #-> /products/1/step2
end
```

This will pass `params[:product_id]` through the process, allowing you to use it on your next step:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def step2
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
end

#app/views/products/step2.html.erb
<%= collection_select(:product, :size_id, @product.size, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
```

Having looked at it, I think your real problem is storing your `size` as a string inside your `Product` model. I'd make a separate model called `sizes`, and then use a join model called `products_sizes` to allow you to associate as many sizes as you need with each product. You'd then be able to call the associative data

---

Why not do this:

```
#app/models/product.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_sizes
    has_many :sizes, through: :product_sizes
end

#app/models/size.rb
Class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_sizes
    has_many :products, through: :product_sizes
end

#app/models/product_size.rb
Class ProductSize < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :size
end
```

This allows you to store sizes for many different products, allowing you to pick ID's from the `ProductSize` model, referencing them directly in your cart model:

```
#app/models/cart.rb
Class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :product_size
end

#carts
id | user_id | product_id | product_size_id | created_at | updated_at
```

This means if you create a new cart item, you'll be able to assign a `product`'s `size` to the record directly:

```
<%= collection_select(:product, :product_size_id, @product.sizes, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
```